# Ошибка при введении команды pip в командную строку

Tags: python, pip, ascii

При установке выдает ошибку UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 1210: ordinal not in range(128).

Версия Python 2.7, в папке Scripts файлы pip присутствуют. Что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не внимательно прочли комментарий @andreymal?. Вас попросили "полный **текст** ошибки".

Comment: Никуда не уезжайте. Роскомнадзор выезжает за вами

Comment: перефразируйте вопрос и возможно Вас поймут.